# Amount of the Payment (tense)

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-tense

Say, previously I received a payment of $100 from Party A, and **NOW** I am describing the amount of the payment: "*The amount of the payment was $100*" (past tense).

Must the past tense be used? Is it possible to use the present tense ("*The amount of the payment is $100*")?

Comment: There are various duplicates discussing the accepted practice of using present simple to describe a past act etc still having present effects (Shakespeare is my favourite playwright). But here, I'd stick with past simple.

Comment: In that sense, even the payment was received ten years ago, say in 2008, because the amount has remained the same since 2008, so when we are NOW describing the amount of the payment, the present tense can be used:

"The amount of the payment I received in 2008 is $100".

Is my analysis correct？